# Order that arguments are pushed on stack on x64

Tags: x86-64, abi

In what order are x64 arguments pushed on to the stack:

- in the System V ABI?
- in the Windows ABI?

I am writing a Java FFI library that uses dynamically generated stubs and these stubs depend on this order.

I *suspect* that it is "floats first" but am not sure.

Comment: You are aware that arguments are passed in registers too? Not just on the stack?

Comment: @jcoder Yes I am.  I have already handled the case of all integer arguments in registers.

Comment: Don't know the System V ABI, but IIRC, in Windows 64, **floating point** registers are passed in `xmm0` up to `xmm3` **instead of** `rcx`, `rdx`, `r8` and `r9`, so if the arguments are `(int, double, int, double)`, they are passed in `rcx`, `xmm1`, `r8` and `xmm3` respectively. The rest, if any, is passed on the stack, as @MargaretBloom describes in her answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [System V ABI, Section 3.2.3](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf):

> Once registers are assigned, the arguments passed in memory are pushed on
>   the stack in reversed (right-to-left) order.

[Windows x64 ABI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx) is very informal and it is doesn't specify the order of the stack parameters.
However from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention) and *common sense* we can reach the same conclusion as above:

> Additional arguments are pushed onto the stack (right to left)